# Mixing Reflection with Standard Calls

Tags: c#, reflection

Let me preface this by saying that I am completely new to reflection.

I have a `Dictionary` of `string` to `Func<string, string>`.  I'd like to add a configuration section that would allow me to define the name of static methods that can be programmatically added into this dictionary.

So basically, I'd have something like this:

```
public static void DoSomething()
{
    string MethodName = "Namespace.Class.StaticMethodName";

    // Somehow convert MethodName into a Func<string, string> object that can be 
    // passed into the line below

    MyDictionary["blah"] = MethodNameConvertedToAFuncObject;
    MyDictionary["foo"] = ANonReflectiveMethod;

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Func<string, string>> item in MyDictionary)
    {
        // Calling method, regardless if it was added via reflection, or not
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value(blah));
    }
}

public static string ANonReflectiveMethod(string AString)
{
    return AString;
}
```

Is it possible to do this, or do I need everything invoked through reflection?

Comment: What are you try to achieve with this becouse i think you are making some serious mistakes.

Comment: @PeterKiss in a nutshell, I'm making a filtering system similar to the one in wordpress.  You'll give the filter a name, then supply a callback method.  I'm using ASP.NET webforms.  I've got it setup to where I can add a filter supplying in a callback method, but I'd like to add "Global Filters", that are essentially added via strings in the web.config.  I do want to note that I'm wanting to filter the data before it's in the response, so a simple HttpModule isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all you're looking for is [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx). You'll need to break the name you've got into a class name and a method name. You can then use [`Type.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx) to get the type, then [`Type.GetMethod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx) to get the `MethodInfo`, then use:

```
var func = (Func<string, string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                            typeof(Func<string, string>), methodInfo);
```

Once you've created the delegate, you can put it into the dictionary with no problems.

So something like:

```
static Func<string, string> CreateFunction(string typeAndMethod)
{
    // TODO: *Lots* of validation
    int lastDot = typeAndMethod.LastIndexOf('.');
    string typeName = typeAndMethod.Substring(0, lastDot);
    string methodName = typeAndMethod.Substring(lastDot + 1);
    Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName, new[] { typeof(string) });
    return (Func<string, string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(Func<string, string>), method);
}
```

Note that `Type.GetType()` will only find types in the currently executing assembly or `mscorlib` unless you actually specify an assembly-qualified name. Just something to consider. You might want to use [`Assembly.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) instead if you already know the assembly you'll be finding the method in.

Comment: I had all of the pieces, I just didn't know how they fit together :).  I ended up using the GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public); overload to specify the static method inclusion.  Do you know if these binding flags are required to get static methods, or if searching by argument types (as in your example) is sufficient to find a static method?  Much appreciated!

Comment: @PaulZaczkowski: Yes, that will find it - and importantly it avoids problems when there are multiple overloads. You'd need to specify binding flags for a non-public method though.